# Getting IntelliJ 12 to put GWT output in the right location

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

For reasons that I have to ask you to accept as a given, I need to have my GWT application be built such that all the output is available at "/Foo/bar/1.0", rather than the normal "/".

Specifically, I need the result of compiling my GWT app inside of IntelliJ to look like this:

```
~/.IntelliJIdea12/system/gwt/Project.534b2263/Test.ef6cd448/run/www/
  - Foo
    - bar
      - 1.0
         - Testing.html
         - Testing.css
         - (other files in here too, like favicon.ico, etc...)
         - WEB-INF
           - (contents left out here)
         - testing
           - testing.devmode.js
           - testing.nocache.js
```

The best I can seem to do is to get the Testing.html, Testing.css, etc... in the right place. I get this by setting the "Output Relative Path" for my GWT module to "/Foo/bar/1.0/" *and* the "Path Relative to DeploymentRoot" for my Web Resource Directory to the same "/Foo/bar/1.0/".

However, the "testing" directory, containing the testing.devmode.js and testing.nocache.js seem to wind up in the ~/.IntelliJIdea12/system/gwt/Project/534b2263/Test.ef6cd448/run/www/testing directory.
Obviously, this means that when the Testing.html tries to include the testing/testing.nocache.js it cannot be found, and my GWT app doesn't work.

Hopefully I'm just missing something easy, but I've been digging around for hours...

For those who may be interested, I've created a sample project to illustrate the problem and posted it, along with this same basic question, at the IntelliJ Forums: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/442050.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future reference and easy of finding this answer, the final result (see http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/442050) it is not possible to control the location of the output of the GWT compiler.

Practically what this means (for my project anyways) is that I have to do a runtime check: GWT.isProdMode() and then load resources from different locations.

Answer (score 0):

(Copied from IntelliJ forums)
If you need to put GWT compiler output somewhere you need to create an artifact (File | Project Structure | Artifacts) and add 'GWT Compiler Output'
element to it. Also you can put 'Web facet resources' element to the same artifact. If you need to place the GWT output into a subfolder under the
artifact output root use 'New Folder' action in the 'Output layout' tree in the artifact editor.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not right. That only affects the construction of the artifact, not the GWT compiler output during debugging.

Comment: If you get the GWT output in the artifact why does it bother you that IDEA firstly generates the GWT Compiler output to some intermediate place under its 'system' directory?

Comment: I'll circle back and post the full solution here after it gets resolved on http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/442050.